# Failed to import quarry.auth

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a bot for Minecraft in python to integrate with Discord. I have this code from the documentation

```
import discord
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from quarry.net.client import ClientFactory, ClientProtocol
from quarry.auth import Profile


class kek:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


class ExampleClientProtocol(ClientProtocol):
    pass


class ExampleClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = ExampleClientProtocol


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main():
    print("logging in...")
    profile = yield Profile.from_credentials(
        "MOJANG EMAIL", "MOJANG PASSWORD")
    factory = ExampleClientFactory(profile)
    print("connecting...")
    factory = yield factory.connect("play.minevibe.net", 25565)
    print("connected!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    reactor.run()


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(kek(client))
```

However, I get the error "MCBot.kek was not loaded. [No module named 'quarry.auth']" when I run it. The rest of the bot runs fine however it does not login to the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [github repo for quarry](https://github.com/barneygale/quarry/tree/master/quarry/net) `auth` is inside the `net` directory so try replacing

```
from quarry.auth import Profile
```

with

```
from quarry.net.auth import Profile
```